# Unet upsampling block execution time: TransposeConv vs. Upsample+Conv2d

Tags: keras, convolution, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I'am trying to implement a binary segmentation model using unet in keras. Here are the upsampling blocks of my networks.

In one model i used normal **transpose convolution**, while in the second one i used **resize bilinear+ conv2d**.

```
# Convolution block with Transpose Convolution
def deconv_block(tensor, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'):

    y = Conv2DTranspose(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=size, strides=2, padding = padding, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)(tensor)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Dropout(0.5)(y)
    y = Activation("relu")(y)


    return y

# Convolution block with Upsampling+Conv2D
def deconv_block_rez(tensor, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'):
    y = UpSampling2D(size = (2,2),interpolation='bilinear')(tensor)
    y = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size,size), padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer)(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = Dropout(0.5)(y)
    y = Activation("relu")(y)


    return y
```

Are they equivalent in terms of **quality and execution time**?
Quality-wise they were found to be almost same(i used 128*128 input); but in terms of execution time they were different.I read in a blog that upsampling+conv2d will not suffer from the problem of **checkerboard artifacts**; but does it happen at the cost of execution time?

Here is a typical block of my network....

> **Upsample:-**
>
> up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 800)  0
>   concatenate_1[0][0]
>   __________________________________________________________________________________________________ batch_normalization_2 (Conv2D)  (None, 16, 16, 256)  1843456
>   up_sampling2d_2[0][0]
>   __________________________________________________________________________________________________ dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 16, 256)  0
>   batch_normalization_2[0][0]
>   __________________________________________________________________________________________________ activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 16, 16, 256)  0
>   dropout_2[0][0]
>
> **Transpose conv:-**
>
> conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 16, 16, 256)  1843456
>   concatenate_1[0][0]
>   __________________________________________________________________________________________________ batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 16, 16, 256)  1024
>   conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]
>   __________________________________________________________________________________________________ dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 16, 16, 256)  0
>   batch_normalization_2[0][0]
>   __________________________________________________________________________________________________ activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 16, 16, 256)  0
>   dropout_2[0][0]

Even though both of them have almost same parameters; the block with **upsample+conv2d has more execution time**(resize-bilinear is taking negligible time) i.e conv vs.  transpose-conv => 154ms vs 35ms).

Clearly the **conv2d has stride 1** in the resize+normal-conv block and **transpose-conv has stride 2**; but both uses 3x3 kernels.And, recently people have begun to use the resize+conv blocks instead of normal transpose convolution.

Does this speed difference happen always or can we use any variation of the upsample+conv2d (say stride 2 or kernel 1x1 )so that execution time is same(also quality shouldn't be degraded) or is it any bug in my code.